# Unable to use value of a variable in javascript to assign a value to a java variable.

Tags: javascript, jsp, scriptlet

I have tried this many a times but unable to do this. first let me put my code. ::

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function delemp(v){
    alert(v);
    <%
    String abc=%>v<%;

    %>
out.println(abc);
}

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var h= "Shantanu";
delemp(h);
});
</script>
```

In the above code. I am calling `delemp(h);`. That should assign value `"Shantanu"` to variable `abc.` and then print that value. But i am unable to do this. when i comment the scriptlet part and run only `alert(v)` it gives me value `Shantanu` that is value is passing to function `delemp(v)`. But unable to assign it to `abc`. It gives me an error ::

```
Type Mismatch: cannot convert from Void to string.
```

Where's the prob? thanks..

Comment: Java is not my language but I would have thought this get compiled before any call to the JS function so it's not possible to assign value in Java from JS

Comment: @gillesc I need to use js variable v in java code(scriptlets).. Is there anything i can do. ? Any way out... I have gt this link .. See the answer over here.. Whats the difference between this and my ques.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9923702/assign-javascript-variable-to-jsp-code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this. The scriptlets are executed on server before the page would be loaded, but javascript - on client. When you execute your js, you're already have the result of evaluating    of the scriptlets and it couldn't be changed with js.